# In Python, the same line raises float division by zero despite contents of said line

Tags: python

So, I have a python file from another piece of software. In said python file, an error occurs when I try to run the software, where it complains that I (or rather, the people that somehow made this) cannot divide by zero:

```
 k = (c - 1.0) / (c + 1.0)
```

At which point, I think, "Fair enough, I'll just prevent that from ever happening."

```
if abs(c+10)<0.001:
    k=0
else:
    k = (c - 1.0) / (c + 1.0)
```

Now instead of getting my original error:

```
File "/home/wurst/Programs/Armory/armsdk//armory/blender/arm/exporter.py", line 1675, in extract_projection
    k = (c - 1.0) / (c + 1.0)
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

I get this:

```
File "/home/wurst/Programs/Armory/armsdk//armory/blender/arm/exporter.py", line 1675, in extract_projection
    if abs(c+10)<0.001:
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

At which point, feeling foolish, I start to peruse python tutorials, but there's nothing on the subject. Even if I leave the line blank, it complains that the blank line is dividing by zero.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing the decimal separator. Replace `c+10` by `c+1.0`

Comment: `c+10 != c+1.0`

Comment: What's the value of c when the exception occurs? Please `print(c) before the line where the error occurs to find out.

Comment: it must be a problem with not resetting the whole compilation, because the said print statement never executes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .pyc file, composed of compiled Python bytecode, is newer than the Python source for some reason. The Python VM is running the old code in the .pyc, but using the new source in the .py to show where the error is. Delete the .pyc file.

Comment: No, wait, that's not right either. even after deleting all the pyc files, it still does it. I'm wondering if it may be storing some make files somewhere...

Comment: Never mind, it seems that the default device through which the python code was executed needed a little twiddling with to realize the bytecode was gone. This is the right answer!

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing a decimal in your if statement.

```
if abs(c + 1.0) < 0.001:
    k = 0
else:
    k = (c - 1.0) / (c + 1.0)
```

Comment: even so, it still gives the error. Good catch anyway, I wrote this up rather quickly.

Answer (score 0):

For this case you **don't** really need to use [abs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#abs).
This should do the job:

```
if (c + 1.0):
    k = (c - 1.0) / (c + 1.0)
else:
    k = 0
```